# mikepenz material drawer can not load url for drawer item

Tags: android, image, url, materialdrawer

I use mikepenz material drawer too, but I met issue about loading URL to update drawer item icon, but still failed. I can not solve it. 
https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

[image]

please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of the latest version of the MaterialDrawer it is now recommend to use the AbstractDrawerImageLoader and overwrite the specific methods.

Using [glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide):

```
//initialize and create the image loader logic
DrawerImageLoader.init(new AbstractDrawerImageLoader() {
        @Override
        public void set(ImageView imageView, Uri uri, Drawable placeholder) {
            Glide.with(imageView.getContext()).load(uri).placeholder(placeholder).into(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel(ImageView imageView) {
            Glide.clear(imageView);
        }
});
```

Or [picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/):

```
//initialize and create the image loader logic
DrawerImageLoader.init(new AbstractDrawerImageLoader() {
        @Override
        public void set(ImageView imageView, Uri uri, Drawable placeholder) {
            Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(uri).placeholder(placeholder).into(imageView);
        }

        @Override
        public void cancel(ImageView imageView) {
            Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).cancelRequest(imageView);
        }
});
```

You can find a full implementation including sample code on how to define different placeholders for different targets in the GitHub repository of the [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer). 
Here's the implementation of the [CustomApplication](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/materialdrawer/app/CustomApplication.java)

Comment: you mentioned it that this code should be in the Application class. So, if i want to change profile pic during runtime, will it work ?

Comment: this code only provides the logic which ImageLoader will be used (like picasso etc...) if you update the profile you can do this.

Comment: thanks. One more question, how can we detect onClick on user profile imageView

Comment: Just define a `withOnAccountHeaderProfileImageListener` on the `AccountHeaderBuilder`

Comment: Last question :) if I have only one account, dropdown icon is still appears. can we remove it ?

Comment: Yes that's really simple too `withSelectionListEnabledForSingleProfile(false)`

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this issue.

The MaterialDrawer supports fetching images from URLs and setting them for the Profile icons. As the MaterialDrawer does not contain an ImageLoading library the dev can choose his own implementation

Need to implement this method in your application class.

```
//initialize and create the image loader logic
DrawerImageLoader.init(new DrawerImageLoader.IDrawerImageLoader() {
  @Override
  public void set(ImageView imageView, Uri uri, Drawable placeholder) {
    Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).load(uri).placeholder(placeholder).into(imageView);
  }

  @Override
  public void cancel(ImageView imageView) {
    Picasso.with(imageView.getContext()).cancelRequest(imageView);
  }

  @Override
  public Drawable placeholder(Context ctx) {
    return null;
  }
});
```

Have fun @.@