# Downloading icons from the network to the mini drawer

Tags: android, url, icons, materialdrawer

I use libraries https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer to create a navigation drawer with mini drawer.
I need to download icons from the network. It turned out to be done for the usual driver, using [mikepenz material drawer can not load url for drawer item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686640/mikepenz-material-drawer-can-not-load-url-for-drawer-item).

if I replace the line
`ImageHolder.applyMultiIconTo(icon, iconColor, selectedIcon, selectedIconColor, isIconTinted, viewHolder.icon)`, on
`ImageHolder.applyTo(icon, viewHolder.icon, "customUrlItem")`, then the icons are displayed.

[image: worked icon]

But if I try to add a selectedIcon, and use
`ImageHolder.applyMultiIconTo(icon, iconColor, selectedIcon, selectedIconColor, isIconTinted, viewHolder.icon)`, then the driver is only shown selectedIcon, and in the miniDrawer does not show the icons.

[image: not worked]
[image: not worked]

An example of how I did it: https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer/commit/8deedf8470f19c74ed6b826fd5aadc4eaed506da

How to fix it?(

Comment: check out this tutorial https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.holder.ImageHolder&method=applyMultiIconTo

Comment: @krishankTripathi, sorry, but it did not help me.

Comment: i hope you will post your whole code soon so it will give us any idea of what you actual issues is

Comment: here is a link to issue that i think might be related https://github.com/mikepenz/CrossfadeDrawerLayout/issues/2